# How to connect two points with a line in two different coordinate system/transforms in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geometry, bezier, d3pie.js

I'm trying to create a closed path by connecting 4 sets of points, but the points are in 2 different `transforms`.

For example, I have three pie charts, two of them are using `d3.layout.pack()` and are inside the bigger pie chart:

```js
var width = 700,
  height = 500,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2,
  thickness = 20,
  length_inner = 2 * Math.sqrt(Math.pow(radius, 2) / 2);

var data = [{
  "name": "bob",
  "toward": "against",
  "fruit": "apple",
  "value": 5
}, {
  "name": "rob",
  "toward": "for",
  "fruit": "apple",
  "value": 9
}, {
  "name": "alice",
  "toward": "for",
  "fruit": "orange",
  "value": 3
}, {
  "name": "mike",
  "toward": "against",
  "fruit": "orange",
  "value": 6
}, {
  "name": "katy",
  "toward": "for",
  "fruit": "orange",
  "value": 8
}]

var data_inner = _(data).chain()
  .groupBy("fruit")
  .map(function(v, k) {
    return {
      "name": k,
      "sum": _(v).chain()
        .pluck("value")
        .reduce(function(memo, num) {
          return memo + num;
        }, 0)
        .value(),
      "data": v
    };
  })
  .value()

var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr({
    "width": width,
    "height": height
  })
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height / 2) + ")");

var outer = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "outer");

var color_outer = d3.scale.category20b();

var arc_outer = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - thickness)
  .outerRadius(radius);

var pie_outer = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })
  .sort(null)
  .padAngle(.02);

var path_outer = outer.selectAll("path")
  .data(pie_outer(data))
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc_outer")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", arc_outer)
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color_outer(d.data["name"]);
  });

var inner = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr({
    "class": "inner",
    "transform": "translate(" + -(length_inner / 2) + "," + -(length_inner / 2) + ")"
  });

var bubble_inner = d3.layout.pack()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.sum;
  })
  .sort(null)
  .size([length_inner, length_inner])
  .padding(10);

var node_inner = inner.selectAll("g.node_inner")
  .data(
    bubble_inner.nodes({
      children: data_inner
    })
    .filter(function(d) {
      return !d.children;
    })
  )
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr({
    "class": "node_inner",
    "transform": function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }
  });

var arc_inner = d3.svg.arc();
var pie_inner = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var arc_inner_g = node_inner.selectAll("g.arc_inner")
  .data(function(d) {
    return pie_inner(d.data).map(function(m) {
      m.r = d.r;
      return m;
    });
  });

arc_inner_g.enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc_inner")
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
    arc_inner.innerRadius(d.r - thickness);
    arc_inner.outerRadius(d.r);
    return arc_inner(d);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d.data.toward === "for" ? "#2ca02c" : "d62728";
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>

<body>
  <svg>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Now I'm trying to connect two points with a Bezier curve from the outer to inner pie chart like this:

[image]

Then close the other two points to create a `<path>` and fill it later (sorry for terrible Photoshop skills):

[image]

I'm trying to avoid having one, unified coordinate system. Even if I had to do that, I'm not sure how since I won't know how to create the two inner circle without `transforms`.

Comment: So if You know what coordinates systems are, maybe You should use some kind of translation function. Like fromPolarToCarthesian ? Its just an idea

Comment: @Take_Care_ And I thought I was joking when I told my teacher that I'll never be using trigonometry in real life... Let's see if that's the only option or if there's an easier way than pure math.

Comment: "pure maths" isn't hard, "complicated pure maths" is, and there is no reason to assume this is hard in any way. If it's easy to set up the transform, then it's easy to set up the inverse transform: just run the coordinates through the reverse tranform (in reverse order, if you have multiple transforms). In this case your transforms are super simple translations, ezpz to compensate.

Comment: Yup, I think I know how to do it. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to draw the path using several `d3.path()` functions:

```
// d is the data attached to the outer pie but also includes
// the respective inner pie's angles, cx, cy, and radius
function link_d_path(d) {
        if(d.value === 0) return "";

        var r_o = radius - thickness,
            offset = -Math.PI / 2,
            path_o_start = d.startAngle + offset,
            path_o_end   = d.endAngle   + offset,
            cx_i = -length_inner / 2 + d.node_x,
            cy_i = -length_inner / 2 + d.node_y,
            path_i_start = d.inner_startAngle + offset,
            path_i_end   = d.inner_endAngle   + offset,
            angle_diff = ((path_o_start + path_o_end) / 2 + (path_i_start + path_i_end) / 2) / 2,
            r_i = d.node_r,
            path = d3_path.path();

        path.arc(0, 0, r_o, path_o_start, path_o_end);
        path.bezierCurveTo(
            r_o * Math.cos(path_o_end),
            r_o * Math.sin(path_o_end),
            cx_i + (r_i + link_radius_cp_offset) * Math.cos(path_i_end),
            cy_i + (r_i + link_radius_cp_offset) * Math.sin(path_i_end),
            cx_i + r_i * Math.cos(path_i_end),
            cy_i + r_i * Math.sin(path_i_end)
        );
        path.arc(cx_i, cy_i, r_i, path_i_end, path_i_start, true);
        path.bezierCurveTo(
            cx_i + (r_i + link_radius_cp_offset) * Math.cos(path_i_start),
            cy_i + (r_i + link_radius_cp_offset) * Math.sin(path_i_start),
            r_o * Math.cos(path_o_start),
            r_o * Math.sin(path_o_start),
            r_o * Math.cos(path_o_start),
            r_o * Math.sin(path_o_start)
        );

        return path.toString();
    }
```

I only needed to convert from polar to cartesian during the Bezier curve. The `path.arc()` already took polar coordinates.

Note that `length_inner` is the offset for the inner pie's cx and cy relative to the outer pie's cx and cy.